# How do I use Union in linq (vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I know how to call the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) extension method, e.g.

```
Dim r = productFirstChars.Union(customerFirstChars)
```

However I do I do this with the Linq syntax, e.g.

```
from productFirstChars select ????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't - not all LINQ operators are supported in query expressions, and `Union` is one of those that isn't. (VB has language support for more query operators than C#, as it happens.) See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384830.aspx) for a list of supported query clauses.

Comment: Thanks trying to Google for a negative answer never work well

Comment: Funny you say VB has better query expressions then C#, I am only using a query expression in the first place as VB has such bad support for lambda expressions.